# How do I VPN out of a Windows Server 2012 R2 system?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I've found plenty of help online for setting up Windows Server 2012 R2 to be a VPN server, but none for having it be a VPN client.  The standard Windows 8.1 methods don't seem to work or even be there at all.  How do you do connect a Windows Server 2012 R2 system as a VPN client to another network?

Thanks!

(To make it clear:  I'm running WinSvr2012R2 on my personal laptop, I want to connect it via VPN to a company's internal network.  I need to configure authentication permissions too (specifically, I need "Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP)" and "Microsoft CHAP Version 2 (MS-CHAP v2)").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also running Windows Server 2012 R2, and I'm able to create a VPN connexion through the **Control Pannel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Setup a new conexion or network**

[image]

Could you have a try a explain what's the issue if you can't do that ?

Comment: I'm embarrassed.  I negligently didn't fully describe the problem which was: even _after_ configuring the right protocols I was getting Error 850 "required protocol not installed".  Your answer prompted me to look further, and the solution was:  You continue getting Error 850 _even after_ disconnecting and setting different security protocols _unless you_ clear your saved credentials before trying again.